# How do I set up multiple routes in Next.js API?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Hey I'm trying to set up my API for my Next.js app. The issue is that I don't really understand how to structure my API routes. I have 3 routes needed -> **get all accounts, create new account, get one account by ID**. My initial thought would be to split them up into three files in the api folder -> **api/getAllAccounts.ts, api/getOneAccount.ts, api/postOneAccount.ts**. And then just send the requests to these endpoints. But I feel like I'm misusing the API in Next here, one of the reasons because I need to send the ID as a param.

I'm thinking about using the Route Handlers here. So then I would create **api/accounts/route.ts**. And in here I would have one GET function to get all the accounts and one POST function to post new. But here I ran into the trouble that I need two GET functions, one for GET one account and one for GET all accounts.

So here I just felt like I'm misunderstanding the basis of Next, and felt I needed some help.

Comment: What is your main src or app file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all accounts, you can use the `api/accounts/route.ts` file with `GET`, and a `POST` to create a new account.

To get a specific account, you should create a new route api/accounts/[id]/route.ts. Here you can create a `GET` function where you can get `id` as params from the URL which you can use to fetch the specific account from your database.

Comment: makes sense, thank you!

Comment: No problem. If you get your answer already, you can approve it.